# Blogger Cond Tag If a Post has "NO" Specific Label

Tags: html, blogger, amp-html

I want to show AMP if NO specific label.

```
<b:attr cond='(data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}) 
and data:view.url == data:view.url params { amp: &quot;1&quot; } 
and data:post.labels none (l =&gt; l.name == &quot;Noamp&quot;)' name='amp' value='amp'/>
```

and also this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;} 
and data:view.url == data:view.url params { amp: &quot;1&quot; } 
and data:post.labels none (l =&gt; l.name == &quot;Noamp&quot;)'>
```

i want to call it when there is no label name "Noamp"
but that code doesn't work. I'm new to Blogger. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label =&gt; label.name in [ &quot;etiqueta&quot; ])'>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.